# Anything that should be done about a user "gutting" questions?

Tags: discussion

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475362/filling-out-uitableview-from-json-file) recently edited it to delete almost all the content.  Looking at his activity, he has done the same with a total of 7 of his questions in the past half-hour.

This makes the questions (which admittedly were not exemplary, but which generally had several fair answers) pretty worthless to future readers.

Is there anything that can/should be done about this?  If I vote down too many of the questions the votes will get reversed as "serial downvoting".

Comment: The user was given a suspension of 7 days to cool down.

Comment: Appreciate Hot Licks, for bringing up this incident.

Comment: Likely the user is trying to remove his code from the web, for whatever reason.

Comment: @TankorSmash - The code wasn't all that special that it would merit hiding, unless it was stolen from somewhere.

Answer (score 52):

Self-vandalism is not acceptable. I'm looking at this now.

You can rollback questions that have been vandalised but avoid getting into edit wars as this just creates more work.

An automatic flag is raised when someone does this and we'll usually pick it up from there, but there's no harm in adding a flag of your own, particularly if you can elaborate and add more insight into what's happening.

Simply confirming that there is vandalism happening helps, because there are also plenty of cases where bulk self-edits aren't vandalism (e.g. updating documentation links).

I don't think downvotes really achieve much - they look odd if the question was reasonable to begin with once the question has been rolled back, but in moderation (e.g. just one or two) they would count towards a Q-ban which might not be a bad thing.

Comment: Looks like the user is completely uprooted/deleted now. Also, the post is deleted by community. shouldn't you be undelete the post.

Comment: I don't mind the user account got deleted; it's better not to have this type of person over SO community but the post looks pretty valid and even the answer is been offered bounty. So, the post must be re-activated.

Comment: @Rahul I've undeleted that post. There was quite a lot of weird stuff going on around this incident.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if voting down is the best thing to do in this case.

I rolled back all those edits except for one.

I'll flag for mod attention if he does anymore.

Comment: The primary thing to do is to roll back to the best state of the posts.