# Why am I unable to get my question reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I would be grateful if somebody could explain why my several attempts to get the following question reopened have failed.

[Why can't I change my callback function name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344013/why-cant-i-change-my-callback-function-name)

I am looking for a detailed explanation for the failure after each of my edits and not a reference to general rules.

I assume those with more power than I have can see the now deleted history and give a full answer.

Comment: The JavaScript / JSONP content of your question is on-topic, but asking for recommendations for an alternative service like `https://json2jsonp.com` or for help using such a site, is not on-topic. So if you can reword your question to focus on the JS stuff, in a way that others can reproduce your problem, then your question will be eligible to be reopened.

Comment: OK - thanks - another rewrite coming - I will attempt to recreate the missing history at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing history"? The complete edit history of a post is normally available to everyone via the `edited` link underneath the post.

Comment: Please stop editing your proposed solution back into the question!

Comment: I have been told in the past by a Stack forum to edit the original where possible. There is not a clear line in this case between an edited question and a solution. It was a journey I took while the question was closed.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is asking us to find you an internet service:

> Does anybody know of a better free json2jsonp service than the following?

You can see what is permitted from the help page:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Information about asking for online services is here:

[Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

However you asked about the edits. You cannot edit to remove or vandalise a question as although the author is still the copyright holder, but by contributing here the author of the post has given consent to Stack Exchange to publish the contents of the post, as per the [CC BY-SA licence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) and you cannot edit to remove content as explained here:

[Anything that should be done about a user "gutting" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275864/anything-that-should-be-done-about-a-user-gutting-questions)

If you wish to show solutions to your own problem, you should do this by answering your own question, and then your learning is recorded for others to learn from. You can even accept your own answer. details are here:

[Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: It started out as what appeared to be a software problem but when I eventually found a likely cause I thought it should be recorded in the same place as the original question which had by then been closed. At this stage I totally rewrote it to overcome the reason for it being closed. I still think it is worth recording somewhere - but where? Unless I get more assistance than I have had I may resign from all stack sites - it is too stressful at my age.

Comment: @NevilleHillyer I updated my answer to explain how you can record the information you have discovered, which is encouraged and welcomed here.

Comment: OTOH, Neville can't post an answer to his question while it's closed. And it won't get reopened in its current state. At the very least, he needs to remove the request for an alternative to `https://json2jsonp.com`.

Comment: OK but I saw the problem as my original post and edits never being accepted so I started again.